# what kind of OS is present inside 'mbed'?

Tags: arm, embedded, stm32, mbed

mbed seems to be a good place to start a new project on ARM. And they are saying that there is an OS inside. Is that real time (RTOS) ? is that capable of multi tasking and inter-task communication ? is there any comparison with FreeRTOS ?

Comment: https://developer.mbed.org/blog/entry/Introducing-mbed-OS-5/

Comment: It literally answers your RTOS question on the linked page.

Comment: Please don't post questions that can be answered by researching, questions are forever. And please have some respect for other users on this site and use proper punctuation, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [release note](https://docs.mbed.com/docs/mbed-os-release-notes/en/latest/5_1/release/) for version 5.1.0:

> mbed OS now incorporates an RTOS.
>
> The RTOS core is based on the widely used open-source CMSIS-RTOS RTX,
>   providing an established kernel that can support threads and other
>   RTOS services on very tiny devices. The RTOS primitives are always
>   available, so that drivers and applications can rely on features such
>   as threads, semaphores and mutexes. The RTOS is initialised ahead of
>   entering the main() thread, enabling components to rely on RTOS
>   facilities even if the core application is single threaded.
>
> The implementation is based on CMSIS-RTOS RTX 4.79.0, and we will be
>   tracking and contributing to the development of CMSIS-RTOS releases,
>   allowing us to pick up support for new versions and architectural
>   features such as TrustZone for Cortex-M.
>
> The MINAR eventing-only scheduler is not included in this release. An
>   alpha version of a more flexible event scheduler library is available,
>   supporting the same design patterns within RTOS threads and
>   components. This library will be merged and managed as part of the
>   core OS codebase once it reaches release maturity.

Comment: Thank you. So is that matured enough to use for a professional project?